# regular expression pattern an input description

Tags: regex

Guys I am doing a regular expression I have an input text that accept between 1 to 3 words that each one has as maximum 15 words. It is working fine but I would like to improve it.  This is my 
pattern:

```
^[A-Za-z]*[\s]{0,1}[A-Za-z\d\-_]{0,15}[\s]{0,15}[A-Za-z\d\-_]{0,15}$
```

Sample (correct) inputs:

```
here you go
the sample
there you are
```

And has been tested in https://regex101.com/

I would like to iterate it at least once and at most 3 times, as in the examples.  I know about `{1,3}`, but how can I use it in my pattern?  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
^[A-Za-z]*[\s]{0,1}[A-Za-z]*{1,3}$
```

Any suggestion proved and tested would be great guys.
Do not worry about performance (but thanks if you do something better).  I just need the iteration part.

Comment: It does not sound quite clear, do you mean you want to shorten the pattern as much as possible? Like [`^(?:\s?[A-Za-z\d_-]{0,15}){1,3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/jG4yP9/1)? This will also match "non-valid" strings though (those starting with `_`, `-`, digits...).

Comment: wow thanks so much . you are the guy. yes that is what i needed.

Comment: @noob posted the same pattern in his answer. Oh, now it is edited. Please double check if the regex is really what you need. BTW, the shortest possible is not always the most precise/efficient one. BTW, you can replace `[A-Za-z\d_]` with `\w`. The whole regex can be written as `^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s[\w-]{0,15}){1,2}$`, I think.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew almost . I did not know about the ?: something was missing thanks. I am not an expert on regular expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes. Sebastian pointed out that optional space would match more than 15 characters at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Each line having three words, each word with maximum length of 15.

**Regex:** `^(?:[A-Za-z]{1,15})(?: [A-Za-z]{1,15}){0,2}$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:[A-Za-z]{1,15})` matches the first word.
- `(?: [A-Za-z]{1,15}){0,2}` matches last two word with no trailing space.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI6wQ3/4)**

Comment: I'm sorry, but you match `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: @SebastianProske: How about now ?

Comment: Based on OPs description and existing regex, i would have come up with `/^[a-z]{1,15}(?:\s+[\w-]{1,15}){0,2}$/i`

Comment: Thanks man . if i use hello it is not working i just changed the {1,2} for {0,2}. This forum is amazing . Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: I forgot to edit `three` to `two`. Did you checked the demo ? Seems to be working fine. What string did you tried ?

Comment: @SebastianProske: I think it's more or less same. You used an extra `word regex` at beginning and I used at end. Moreover OP didn't specified numbers to be included so I didn't used `\w`.

Comment: OPs regex contains `[A-za-z\d-_]` for the possible second and third word, so I just replaced it with `[\w-]`, not sure if this was an error in the original expression or an unmentioned requirement.

Comment: @SebastianProske: I see your point now. Noted and edited the regex. But `\w` wasn't mentioned. Didn't saw number in OP's string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one; it works for me.

```
^(\w{1,15}\s+){0,2}\w{1,15}$
```

- The first group `(\w{1,15}\s+){0,2}` used to capture 0 or 2 words with their spaces with the
  length is between 1 and 15.
- The second part `\w{1,15}` in order to select without capture the last word.
- And `^` to specify the start and `$` for the end.